# Add test In App purchase to live ios

Tags: distriqt

I want to test a new in-app purchase on a live app before the IAP goes live. I don't see any way to associate the IAP with the Test Flight version.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the "Testing In-App Purchase Products" guide from Apple but the key points are:

> To perform testing for In-App Purchase products:
>
> - Set up test user accounts within Users and Roles in iTunes Connect, as detailed in Creating Sandbox Tester Accounts in iTunes Connect Developer Guide.
>     You’ll need a test user for each territory you want to test the app in.
> - Clear any account information stored on your test device. This prevents an actual user account from automatically being used when testing.
> - Use your test account credentials to test the purchase.

You can setup your sandbox test users in iTunesConnect. The following has detailed information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW10

The products must be real products ready to go live with your next release however you should be able to test them beforehand.